# Simulate fat tail data in R

Tags: r, distribution, simulate, probabilistic-programming

I need to simulate data in R with a fat tail distribution, and having never simulated data before I'm not sure where to start. I have looked into the `FatTailsR` package but the documentation is pretty cryptic and I can't seem to find any obvious tutorials.

Basically, I want to create an artificial dataframe with two columns (X and Y), of 10,000 observations, that uses the following logic/iterations:

- For each observation of X there is an 75% probability that Y is 0, and 25% probability Y is 1 (assigning every observation a 0 or 1).
- Next, look only at the observations of X where Y is 1. Of these observations (25% of the original dataset) there is a 25% that Y is 2.
- Of the observations where Y is 2, 25% get bumped up to 3.
- And iterate so on up to Y = 10.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Including suggestions of packages and functions to check out (maybe something like `rlnorm` ?)

Comment: It would be great to see what you've tried on this. Seems like a `for` loop and one of `runif` or `sample` or `rbinom` is all you need. Your first bullet is `y = sample(0:1, size = 10000, prob = c(0.75, 0.25), replace = TRUE)`. Or `y = ifelse(runif(10000) > 0.75, 1, 0)`. Or `y = rbinom(10000, size = 1, prob = 0.25)`. Pick your favorite syntax. (Also, what's the point of the `X` column? You mention it a lot, but never talk about its values. Seems like it would be simpler to just generate a vector `Y` since `X` doesn't do anything...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work (not super-efficient, but ...)

First figure out the probabilities of each outcome (P(1)=0.75, P(2)=0.75*0.25, P(3)=0.75*0.25^2 ...)

```
cc <- cumprod(c(0.75,rep(0.25,9)))
```

Choose a multinomial deviate with these probabilities (N=1 for each sample)

```
rr <- t(rmultinom(1000,size=1,prob=cc))
```

Figure out which value in each row is equal to 1:

```
storage.mode(rr) <- "logical"
out <- apply(rr,1,which)
```

Check results:

```
tt <- table(factor(out,levels=1:10))
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
756 183  43  14   3   1   0   0   0   0
```

There might be a cleverer way to set this up in terms of a modified geometric distribution ...

Comment: I started down this path, but in OP's iterative procedures the 2s are made out of the 1s, so `P(1) = 0.25 - sum(0.25^(2:10))`. (And I think you have a typo, the original P(1) in the first iteration is 0.25, not 0.75).

Comment: If we do go this way, then I thought the probs of numbers 1:10 are  `0.25^(1:10) - c(rev(cumsum(0.25^(10:2))), 0)` respectively, but I've got a bug because they should sum to `0.25` an this sums to `0.2222252`.

Comment: But I also forgot about the zeros. Feel free to edit if you get around to it before I do, or post your own corrected version (I'll delete if necessary).

Comment: Eh, seems like homework so I probably won't post an answer unless OP shows a fair bit of code. Nice little puzzle though.

Comment: Ugh, I was overcomplicating it with the `cumsum` and all. The probability of `1:10` is `p = 0.25^(1:10); p = p - c(p[-1], 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I understood from your question :

```
data <- data.frame(X=1:10000, Y=sample(c(0,1), 10000, TRUE, prob=c(0.75, 0.25)))
head(data)

pos <- which(data$Y == 1)
pos <- sample(pos, floor(0.25*length(pos)), FALSE)  # 25% of Y == 1

data[pos, "Y"] <- data[pos, "Y"] + 1

## Iterate using a while loop :

data <- data.frame(X=1:10000, Y=sample(c(0,1), 10000, TRUE, prob=c(0.75, 0.25)))
head(data)

i <- 0

while(i < 10) {
  pos <- which(data$Y == (i + 1))
  pos <- sample(pos, floor(0.25*length(pos)), FALSE)  # 25% of Y == 1

  data[pos, "Y"] <- data[pos, "Y"] + 1

  i <- i + 1
}

hist(data$Y)
```

Comment: Nice answer!, For a known number of iterations, seems like `for(i in 1:10)` would be simpler and safer than incrementing `i` manually in a `while` loop.